# difference between two fields from different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

let's say this is the result of my Select query :

```
ID    Name    Status    Edit    Date
1     n1      closed    edt1      01/01/2005
1     n1      closed    edt2      15/01/2005
1     n1      closed    edt3      20/01/2005
```

What I'm trying to do, is to get the diff between the date of edit1 and the date of edit2 (how many days the edit took) and put it on a separate column.

keep in mind that I get a result (for testing purpose), something like this :

```
select x.id, x.name, x.status, y.edit, y.date
from (table1 x left join table2 y on x.id = y.id)
where x.id = 1
```

So how can I get the number of days spent between each edit and put it on a decicated column? of course there won't be a `where x.id = 1` anymore...my query result should look like this :

```
id    name    status    edit_1(edt2 - edt1)   edit_2(edt3 - edt2)   
1     n1      closed    14                    5
```

Thanks for helping ^^

Comment: if your first Select-statement would return a fourth dataset, should there be a 6h column "edit_3(edt4-edt1)" in your final select? (etc?)

Comment: @Mr.Yellow the number of edits will always be the same, let's say 3 edits.. (there can't be no edt3 if edt2 is not done yet)

Comment: ^ that isn't what he's asking.  he's saying edt1, edt2, edt3 all exist and now there's edt4.  Does this require an extra column "edit_3(edt4-edt1)"?

Comment: Also your second column is incorrectly labeled.  It's not the difference between edt3 and edt1, it's ed3-edt2.

Comment: @Aushin yes if we have edt4 this will require edt4-edt3. label was updated on my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD()` analytic function:

```
SELECT id, name, status, edit, date, LEAD(date) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) - date AS edit_diff
  FROM mytable;
```

If you want to put a certain number of edits into their own columns, you could then PIVOT the date returned from the above query; if the # of edits is arbitrary then you'll need to use PL/SQL to do it.

Note that I'm assuming that `name` and `status` won't vary by `id`; if you want to track edits to these then you'll want to add those columns to the `LEAD()` partition.

---

Assuming that you'll always have a fixed number of dates (let's assume three as in your example, giving two date differences), you can pivot by using conditional aggregation. We'll use our query above as a common table expression (CTE); you can also use it as a subquery if that's more your style. I think this way is cleaner though. I'm going to add a call to `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH mydata AS (
    SELECT id, name, status, edit, date
         , LEAD(date) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) - date AS edit_diff
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) AS rn
      FROM mytable
)
SELECT id, name, status, edit, date
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN edit_diff END) AS edit_1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN edit_diff END) AS edit_2
  FROM mydata
 GROUP BY id, name, status, edit, date;
```

(By the way, `date` is not a good name for a column. I'm assuming that's just an example and not the actual name.)

Comment: Those Analytics fuctions seem to be the best way to go..I will read about them tonight. if I can have an example of using pivot (in my example) that would be awesome :)

Comment: unfortunately I can't use `pivot` because the version of Oracle is 10g... Is there any alterntive ? (I found `DECODE` as a solution but I have no Idea how to use it in my case..)

Comment: Will there always be 3 dates, so as to show two edits? Let me know and I will edit my answer - you can use conditional aggregation to pivot.

Comment: Went ahead and did it anyway. If you don't have a fixed (or at least, a maximum) number of dates then a PL/SQL solution would be necessary. Even Oracle 11g's `PIVOT` function can only use fixed values.

Comment: Thnaks for your update :) I will try it as soon as i get access to the database. to answer you questions : yes, the number of edits is always the same, and the edits will always happen in the same order (I have a table `myedittable` (id, edit,order,date). talking about the names of tables and columns, yes those are all examples :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add an incrementing id column like this: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/AutoNumber_and_Identity_columns and then write your query like this:

```
select x.id, x.name, x.status, y.edit, y.date, y.date - z.date
from (table1 x left join table2 y on x.id = y.id left join table2 z on y.newid = z.newid - 1)
where x.id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EditTry]
(
[ID] [int] NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Edit] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[EditTry] ([ID], [Name], [Status], [Edit], [Date]) VALUES (1, N'n1', N'closed', N'edt1', '2005-01-01')
INSERT [dbo].[EditTry] ([ID], [Name], [Status], [Edit], [Date]) VALUES (1, N'n1', N'closed', N'edt2', '2005-01-15')
INSERT [dbo].[EditTry] ([ID], [Name], [Status], [Edit], [Date]) VALUES (1, N'n1', N'closed', N'edt3', '2005-01-20')


with tempss as
(
SELECT ID,Edit,[Date],RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Edit) AS Rank FROM EditTry 
)

select t1.*,datediff(dd,t1.date,(select top 1 date from tempss t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t1.rank < t2.rank)) as Dif from tempss t1
```

Working in SQL Server

Comment: OP is looking for an Oracle solution.